# How to add font-awesome icons from sources with SASS?

Tags: reactjs, sass, icons

I'm creating a React/Ionic project and using SASS for styling, but I had a hard time adding the stylings to the project.

I went to the [font-awsome](https://icomoon.io/app) website, created the package, added the fonts and added the file call to my routes file. But when I use the icons, they don't appear.

the fonts folder:

[image]

font-awesome.module.scss file:

```
  @font-face {
   font-family: 'cbm-icons';
   src        : url('./fonts/cbm-icons.eot?uwy7j0');
   src        : url('./fonts/cbm-icons.eot?uwy7j0#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('./fonts/cbm-icons.ttf?uwy7j0') format('truetype'),
   url('./fonts/cbm-icons.woff?uwy7j0') format('woff'),
   url('./fonts/cbm-icons.svg?uwy7j0#cbm-icons') format('svg');
   font-weight : normal;
   font-style  : normal;
   font-display: block;
  }

  [class^="cb-"],
  [class*=" cb-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family   : 'cbm-icons' !important;
  speak         : never;
  font-style    : normal;
  font-weight   : normal;
  font-variant  : normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height   : 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing : antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 }

 .cb-cross:before {
   content: "\ea0f";
 }

 .cb-checkmark:before {
   content: "\ea10";
 }

 .cb-warning:before {
  content: "\ea07";
 }
```

Here is the import in file in my routes file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [wiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5378489/wiz) recommendations, but tweaked it and did it my way. I took the opportunity to make some changes to my code.

So i did like this. First, I centered all my styling in `global.scss`. Including the style imports from ionic and the @mixin I created from font-awesome:

```
        @import './variables.module.scss';
        @import './font-awesome.module.scss';

        @import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';
        @import '@ionic/react/css/normalize.css';
        @import '@ionic/react/css/structure.css';
        @import '@ionic/react/css/typography.css';
        @import '@ionic/react/css/padding.css';
        @import '@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css';
        @import '@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css';
        @import '@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css';
        @import '@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css';
        @import '@ionic/react/css/display.css';

        @include font-awesome;

        // the rest of the global styling...
        }
```

`font-awesome.scss` file settings:

```
     @mixin font-awesome {
      // file settings...
     }
```

And in the `router.tsx` file I left only the call to `global.scss`:

```
    import 'src/presentation/styles/global.scss'
    // remaining importations...

    const Router: React.FC = () => {
      return (
        // Routes...
      )
    }

    export default Router
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of setting this up:

First, edit **scss/variables.scss** and edit the **$fa-font-path** variable to point to where your webfonts are.
Then, just add to your main (in your case, global) scss file:

```
  @import "./fontawesome/scss/fontawesome.scss";
```

Then you can use the mixins as follows:

```
.twitter {
@extend %fa-icon;
@extend .fab;

&:before {
  content: fa-content($fa-var-twitter);
}
```